# What are best practices for IPhone web development

Tags: iphone, ipad, html

I need to know best practices for IPhone/IPAD HTML5 Web development.

Comment: Your question is far to unspecific to be answered properly.

Comment: I am developing HTML 5 Website for IPhone and IPAD. I need to use video tag also. I wanna to avoid common mistakes. So I wanna to know what I should do or don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember never to rely on "hover" states, because there is no hover on touch devices like the iPhone or the iPad.

Also, for the video tag, remember that you have to use video encoded in H264 (the only format supported by Apple) and that you'd better not use the poster attribute if you need it to work on iPhones without OS 4 (it was an old bug, now fixed). More info here: http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody